# SUMPRODUCT of large area with differing data types

Tags: excel, types

I'm having an issue with counting the number of occurrences of a particular company name during different months of the year.

I have a large spreadsheet set out like the below:

```
             employee 1                    employee 2
Date         Client      Cost              Client         Cost
01/01/2013   test44      £200              test14         £522
02/01/2013   test2       £226              test3          £555
03/01/2013   test3       £300              test63         £400
```

I'd like to count the number of occurrences of a particular client name within a given month, for example, "test3" occurs twice in January, so I'd create the below formula as an attempt:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(F$5:T$369="test3"),--(MONTH($D$5:$D$369)=1))
```

However a VALUE# Error is returned stating wrong data type, I'm aware this is because of the varying data types in my sheet, is it possible for it to ignore incompatible data types and empty cells?

Alternative, is there a way to `sumproduct` each client column against the dates column instead of the entire sheet of incompatible data types? I've attempted this also but it always returns 0, i.e:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(F$5:F$369="test3"),--(H$5:H$369="test3"),--((MONTH($D$5:$D$369)=1))
```

Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if I'm making no sense whatsoever and I'll try to re-explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F$5:T$369="test3")*(MONTH($D$5:$D$369)=1))
```

Comment: Hi JosieP, Thats brilliant and works like a charm, thanks for your help. Can you explain how the * differs from ),--( ? I've never used it before.

Comment: the version you had passes _two separate arrays_ to the SUMPRODUCT function, which requires its arrays to have the same dimensions, hence the error. using * creates _one multi-column array_ which is passed to SUMPRODUCT (which then just totals it)

Comment: That'll help me alot in the future, thanks again for your help.